# Javascript to Actionscript 2.0

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I have a document in Flash in Actionscript 2.0 and I would like to use it with Javascript.
It happens that most solutions I find are always for Actionscript 3.0.
The solution that I found most is this code:

```
ExternalInterface.add_addCallback("PlayMovie", PlayMovie);
```

Now, I want to use it in Actionscript 2.0 but I don't know how to do it and if I need more code than this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExternalInterface is available in both Actionscript 2.0 (starting with Flash Player 8) and 3.0.  The usage is pretty similar in both, but here's an example in AS2:

http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/08/16/external-interface/